How to stop window service using another window service?
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();
sc.ServiceName = "UploadDownloadService";
if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{
    sc.Stop();
    sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
}
                            

I'm trying to stop UploadDownloadService using above code but it's throwing an exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot open UploadDownloadService
service on computer '.'.'
Win32Exception: Access is denied

This is when I'm debugging the code in debug mode and both the services are present in same local machine.
How to get access?
I'm expecting that UploadDownloadService will stop on execution of the above code

Services aren't files. The error says the account executing the code doesn't have permission either to list or stop services, not that they "in use". Post the full exception text returned by Exception.ToString(), not just the message. Right now we can't tell if .Status or .Stop() throw
